# Use :after pseudo element on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 images on my website.

When I click them, I want to add an overlay to them. This overlay is created using the `after` pseudo class.

However, as you can see in my demo, it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hntuf/

```js
jQuery(".option").on('click',function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('option optionActive');
});
```

```css
.option::after, .optionActive::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.optionActive::after {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.col-md-4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-md-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="debttype" data-type_id="1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="debttype" data-type_id="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hntuf/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have changed some css please check this.

```js
jQuery(".option").on('click',function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('option optionActive');
});
```

```css
.optionActive{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.optionActive:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
}

.col-md-4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-4 {
      flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
      max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="debttype" data-type_id="1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="debttype" data-type_id="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add this in our code. Thanks

```
  .option::after, .optionActive::after {
     content: " ";
   }
```

Comment: Remove `display: none;` also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Content:'';` in your css read more abot [pseudo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) element.

```js
jQuery(".option").on('click',function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('option optionActive');
});
```

```css
.option::after, .optionActive::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  content:'';
}

.optionActive::after {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.col-md-4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-md-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="debttype" data-type_id="1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="debttype" data-type_id="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pseuso element like after or before doesn't work without content property. You have to specify content in your css.Below is the code snippet.You can read more about after [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

```js
jQuery(".option").on('click',function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('option optionActive');
});
```

```css
.option::after, .optionActive::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content:"";
  color: #FFF;
}

.optionActive::after {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.col-md-4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-md-4 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="debttype" data-type_id="1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="option">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="debttype" data-type_id="1">
  </div>
</div>
```